# Hide a specific row in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On select of the dropdown field: database I want to hide specific rows, but only the fields under database.  How can I hide only part of the row while keeping others in place?  I tried to use JQUERY and attach an ID to the row but the whole row was deleting, and I want to keep the right side.

I know I can do style visibility: hidden, but I want the rows to disappear and move up if the fields are not needed.

```
    <tr>
<th>* Database</th>
<th class="th_background" style="border-right-style: groove;"><select id="database" class="form-control" name="database" onchange="database_details()">
                        <option value="oracle" selected="selected">Oracle</option>
                        <option value="mssql">Sql Server</option>
                        <option value="teraData">TeraData</option>
                        <option value="epic">Generic ODBC(Chronicles)</option>
                        <option value="sas">SAS</option>
                </select>
                </th>
                <th class="th_background"><input type="radio" name="refreshTde"
                    value="yes" checked> <span data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="This option creates new TDE or replaces existing TDE file with full data.">Full
                        Refresh <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span></th>
                <th class="th_background"><input type="radio" name="refreshTde"
                    value="no"> <span data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="This option appends existing TDE. Should have same data items in the SQL.">Incremental
                        Refresh <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span></th>

</tr>

<tr>
<th>* Service ID</th>
                <th class="th_background"><input type="text" id="sidText"
                    name="sid" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Enter SID"></th>
<th colspan="2" style="background-color: #0072bc;"><span
                    style="color: white;">* SQL Query to Generate TDE</span></th>
```

I just want to hide and collapse this part:

`<th>* Service ID</th>
                    <th class="th_background"><input type="text" id="sidText"
                        name="sid" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Enter SID"></th>`

http://jsfiddle.net/wf7j5tn8/

Answer (score 0):

You can attach classes to the rows, or just use whatever queryselector will work for you.

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('option')
var headers = document.querySelectorAll('th')
options[3].style.display = "none"
headers[2].style.display = "none"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/stdtheme.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" type="text/css">
<table class="w3-table-all" style="width:100%">
<tbody><tr>
 <th>Number</th>
 <th>First Name</th>
 <th>Last Name</th>  
 <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Eve</td>
 <td>Jackson</td>  
 <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>John</td>
 <td>Doe</td>  
 <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Adam</td>
 <td>Johnson</td>  
 <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>Jill</td>
 <td>Smith</td>  
 <td>50</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<select id="database" class="form-control" name="database" onchange="database_details()">
                        <option value="oracle" selected="selected">Oracle</option>
                        <option value="mssql">Sql Server</option>
                        <option value="teraData">TeraData</option>
                        <option value="epic">Generic ODBC(Chronicles)</option>
                        <option value="sas">SAS</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Hmmm not entirly what I am getting at.  Look at my fiddle I have a table with multiple <th> in each row, and I want to hide that side and move the other th up in the next row, without making changes to the right side of my table.

Comment: Still a bit confused, but in reality all you have to do is display = "none", everything else will be handled by the normal flow, or is that bothering you?

Comment: If I do display none then the right side of my table moves over to the left.  I tried making it position fixed but still happening.

Comment: You can float:right, then it stays to the right side

Comment: Yeah, now I understand your problem, didn't take a proper look at the fiddle sry :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should be able to just add a class to the elements you want to hide, then use that class to apply 'display: none' to those elements.

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf7j5tn8/4/) updated with what I mean.

And here's the relevant code from that fiddle:

HTML

```
<th class="hidden">* Service ID</th>
<th class="th_background hidden"><input type="text" id="sidText"
  name="sid" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Enter 
  SID">
</th>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this will actually hide the fields but the right side of the table will be moved to the left and I want it in fixed position.

Comment: I created this reduced test case to get rid of some of the noise and better highlight the problem you're having. http://jsfiddle.net/kr7davku/2/ I haven't figured out a good solution yet though...

Answer (score 0):

Exact Solution might be this

```
<th id="dataHide">* Service ID</th> <!-- add id dataHide to your th -->

//add these to js function
$("input#sidText").css("visibility", "hidden"); 
$("#dataHide").css("visibility","hidden");
```

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/wf7j5tn8/7/

---

The other way is that you disable the field, I would not want to hide a feature from users, rather just disable it

`$("input#sidText").prop('disabled','disabled');`

HTML

```
<tr id="dataHide"> <!-- id assigned here to hide the the row -->
<th>* Service ID</th>
<th class="th_background"><input type="text" id="sidText" name="sid" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Enter SID"></th>
<th colspan="2" style="background-color: #0072bc;"><span style="color: white;">* SQL Query to Generate TDE</span></th>
</tr>
```

js/jQuery

```
function database_details() {
   $("#dataHide").hide(); //hides the id (#) dataHide assigned to the TR, hence removing the whole row. 
    //give this id (dataHide) to any element you want to hide on change of select dropdown 
}
```

This will work. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: but this will hide the whole row and I only want to hide the first two th while keeping the other th there.  Is it possible to make nested tr rows and just set the width to 50%? and then use this to hide the first one??

Comment: In your comment you say "give this id (dataHide) to any element you want to hide..." However, IDs should never be applied to more than one element. You should use a class in this case.

Comment: @jennEDVT Yea, remove the ID from the current element and give it to another one. I wrote it judging that the op has knowledge about it that "id's should not be applied to more than one element".